# Check if user liked a page in facebook works only on me?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a strange problem, I'm trying to see if user liked a page, but it only works on me ? 
I do it this way. What could be the problem ?

```
 FB.api('/me/likes/' + page_id, function(api_response) {
            try {
                if ((api_response.data[0].name) != undefined){
               }else{
              }
            }
            catch (e) {
            }
        });
```

And this way.

```
  var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id="+page_id+" and uid=me()";   
 FB.api(
        {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: fql_query
        },
        function(rows) {
              if (rows.length == 1) {

              } else {

      }
          });
```

It works when I am in my account , but when I logg into someone else`s It doesn't ? This is from application in my account and sandbox mode is OFF so I think it should work, but it doesn't .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this other account explicitly grant Like permissions for your app?

If not, then this is by design. Unless the other user account has granted permission for your app to request likes, your app won't be able to query the user.

Comment: Did the other user account install the app?

Comment: It worked,  maybe the page was cached.. and didn't result the changes I had made . thnks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the facebook page (page_id).  Is the other user you're trying to use able to pull page stats?  Most likely the user does not have manage page permissions.